# Can't load workbook in Jupyter using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to load a workbook into Jupyter using openpyxl.  I always got error message saying:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/bchen13/BY_REGION.xlsx'.  Much appreciated if someone could help out.

I am using Win7, the file is saved in a local folder.  The folder path:

```
\\bhnotoptops1.nesbittburns.ca\userdata$\bchen13\home\02_Work Folder Backup\07_MyWealth_Adoption\Report_201903'
```

> openpyxl.**version** 
>   2.5.3

Jupyter 5.5.0

```
import os
import openpyxl

os.getcwd()
return 'C:\\Users\\bchen13'
path_1 = "C:\\Users\\bchen13\\BY_REGION.xlsx"    
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(path_1)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/bchen13/BY_REGION.xlsx'

Comment: The file does indeed exist at that location, yes?

Comment: The excel is in that folder: \bhnotoptops1.nesbittburns.ca\userdata$\bchen13\home\02_Work Folder Backup\07_MyWealth_Adoption\Report_201903 '

Comment: If `os.path.exists(path_1)` returns `False`, it's unlikely to be an openpyxl problem. The `pathlib`(https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module can be quite helpful here. P.S. probably a good idea to redact your employer's network info from your code.

Comment: You said above the file `BY_REGION.xlsx` is stored in 1) "C:/Users/bchen13/" and also 2) "\\bhnotoptops1.nesbittburns.ca\userdata$\bchen13\home\02_Work Folder Backup\07_MyWealth_Adoption\Report_201903\" ?